# How to add pdfTemplateResolver for Thymeleaf configuration in my jhipster application

Tags: thymeleaf, jhipster

I have an application generated with jhipster, it makes use of Thymeleaf to render email templates. All works nice.

I want to add a pdf generator for which i will to use the thymeleaf templates. So i would like to add a ClassLoaderTemplateResolver. I have this:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThymeleafConfiguration.class);

  @Bean
  @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5 emails")
  public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("mails/");
    emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
    emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);
    return emailTemplateResolver;
  }

  @Bean
  @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5 emails")
  public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver pdfTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("pdf/");
    emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
    emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);
    return emailTemplateResolver;
  }
}
```

Which makes it possible to put the templates in a different directory.

What is unclear to me is how do you make sure i get the pdf template resolver for pdf's and the email template resolver for generating emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems both get picked up automatically. Not sure what will happen when a template name is in both places. To avoid that i could add two beans like this:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
     final Set<TemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new HashSet<TemplateResolver>();
     templateResolvers.add(emailTemplateResolver());
     engine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
    return engine;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine pdfTemplateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
     final Set<TemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new HashSet<TemplateResolver>();
     templateResolvers.add(pdfTemplateResolver());
     engine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
    return engine;
}
```